# $wpdb - Call to a member function insert() on null

Tags: php, database, wordpress

So I am trying to create function for my plugin that will simply insert data into my table but its spitting out the Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in ...

```
function em_db_add_event_(array $data) {     
    global $wpdb;    
    $table_name = 'em_events';     
    $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data); 
  }
```

I tried puting it out of function but that doesnt work either.
Another function that is defined right above that is also using the $wpdb, but for creating table works just fine.

Comment: Where/how are you calling `em_db_add_event_()`? It’s possible that the function is being called before the `$wpdb` global has been defined.

Comment: In what hook or situation you are calling the function?
it may be because the $wpdb is not defined where you are running it.
Also the table name seems to have problem. you should use $table_prefix before the table name. and also the table prefix can be different in different sites.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first declare the $data attribute

```
function em_db_add_event_($data) {     
global $wpdb;
$table_name = 'em_events';     
$wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);
}

$data = array('table_column_name' => 'table_column_value', 'table_column_name2'   => 'table_column_value2' );
em_db_add_event_($data);
```